# Packet processing order of inet, ip and ip6 address families in nftables?

Tags: nftables

`nftables` has families `ip` for IPv4, `ip6` for IPv6 and `inet` for both.

```
# Match IPv4 and IPv6
table inet filter {
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
    tcp dport 443 accept
  }
}

# Match IPv4
table ip filter {
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
    tcp dport 443 accept
  }
}

# Match IPv6
table ip6 filter {
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
    tcp dport 443 accept
  }
}
```

What is the processing order in this case?